# Remove all localizations from an Xcode project

Tags: xcode, localization, xcode5

I've just started a new project (a Cocoa App) with Xcode 5. Since I don't need to internationalize it, I would like to remove all the localized files. I tried many ways to achieve this but once I've delete all the localized files, Xcode shows this error:

```
/Users/johann/Development/imgur-osx/imgur-osx/Images.xcassets: The output directory "/Users/johann/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/imgur-osx-ciprlytowvculvdjzzcpbvlnycts/Build/Products/Debug/imgur-osx.app/Contents/Resources" does not exist.
```

It seems like Xcode doesn't create the `Resources` folder without any localized file. If I create it manually, the project can be compiled without matter. Same goes if I remove the `Image.xcassets` file, but if I add it again it fails.

To remove the localized files, I tried by clicking [the `-` button in the localization section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBgyo.png) and I also tried to delete by hand each localized file (in different orders), without success.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I thought if there is no localization needed then you should use the **base internationalization**.

*As it states in the tooltip*:

> Choosing this option moves the interface files from the development region into the Base localization folder

Check the box under the localizations in the **Project info** tab.
[image]I use the Base internalization.